# JSON in .NET C#/Csharp - Getting values out of the object

Tags: c#, .net, json

I want to parse some JSON data. I'm using [James Newton-King's JSON.NET library](http://james.newtonking.com/pages/json-net.aspx).

I parse the JSON string into a JObject. Here is the JSON I'm parsing:

```
"root": [
{
  "date": 1325400000000,
  "id": 12313131,
  "loc": "en_us",
  "name": "New York, NY",
  "products": [
    {
      "@type": "asdf",
      "city": "New York - Penn Station, NY (NYP)",
      "code": "USA",
    }
  ],
  "summary": {
    "alert": [],
    "end": 1325577000000,
    "start": 1325400000000
  }
}
]
}
```

As you can see it's pretty complex. The "root" was necessary because otherwhise the data could not be parsed into a JObject instance.

```
JObject o = JObject.Parse(jsonString);
```

The JSON data is quite large. There are multiple items in it with different IDs. I want to find an item with a specifid ID.

The problem is, when I try to foreach through the data it has only one element.

```
KEY: root
VALUE: the other stuff.
```

So how do I get to the other stuff and cycle through what's inside?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Nevermind..

I just solved it.

I removed the trailing [ and the end ].

So it is now a Valid Json object and Key Value foreach is working like a charm..

```
            foreach (KeyValuePair<String, JToken> d in o)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(String.Format("Key: {0}; Value: {1}", d.Key, d.Value));
            }
```

Hurray!

Turned out this is only a partial solution. Because now the others are not formatted only the first segment is. The others somehow disappear... :S Damn this...

Even better solution... I was a complete idiot...

Leave everything in place and simply use `JArray ja = JArray.Parse(stringOfJson);`

This will give you an array full with all the data free to cycle through... Awesome. :)