# How to filter out string

Tags: c#, string

How do i filter out to obtain the text ("I can provide....")? The program im using has no variable that contains just this text. Thanks!

```
{
  "session_id": "9643039c-edf0-435a-8345-fc225859a6de"
}
{
  "output": {
    "generic": [
      {
        "response_type": "text",
        "text": "I can provide you with directions, locations and operating hours as of now."
      }
    ],
    "intents": [
      {
        "intent": "Function",
        "confidence": 0.30141472287041043
      }
    ],
    "entities": []
  }
}
{}
```

Comment: Deserialize the JSON, extract the value.

Comment: [Related](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9526440/3181933)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks...took me longer than it should have but here it the code:

```
            string response = dialog.Message();
            JObject data = JObject.Parse(response);
            Console.WriteLine(data["output"]["generic"].First["text"]);
            string text = data["output"]["generic"].First["text"].ToString();
```